Operating system error 1326(The user name or password is incorrect)
I have been working with mapping drives inside sql server.
I mapped something similar to this:
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use y: "\\my_server\Initialed Folders\MM" @@__password__@@ /User:mycompany\m_miorelli /persistent:NO'

and that was more than 3 months ago.
by now I have changed my password.
then when I go to the same sever, lets call it my_server,
and I run this
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use'

I get this result:

you see there is a z: drive still hanging there, I don't know exactly how, maybe I mapped it... persisted
When I try any operation that involve the server where the backups live
I get this error message:
restore filelistonly from disk=N'\\backup_server\ Initialed Folders\MM\backup_of_a_database.bak'


Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
Cannot open backup device '\\backup_server\ Initialed Folders\MM\backup_of_a_database.bak'. Operating system error 1326(The user name or password is incorrect.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.

I have tried doing this:
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use  \\ip\xxx pass /user:xxx /persistent:no'


question(s):
how can I get rid of that mapped drive?
or
very specific objective: how can I get rid of this wrong password thing?
this is not happening in any other server.
Update
Following the advice from Craig in the comments, thanks Craig,
I removed my mapped drive
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'NET USE Z: /d'


That made me happy and thankful, However, that did not solve the issue.


NET USE Z: /d is the basic command to remove a drive mapping.  Even if that was mapped persistently, originally, it shouldn't re-map again if deleted

Just my two cents' worth, but all of this seems so yucky.  You'd be better off either just using UNC paths, or creating backup devices (that reference the required UNC paths), and give the SQL Server and/or SQL Server Agent service accounts the necessary permissions to those network resources.  (Although, if your SQL Server / Agent currently run as local server accounts, they'd need to be changed to domain accounts)

there were entried in the registry related to that mapped drive.
I had to do quite a few things to get this sorted, including rebooting the box a few times.
make sure you access the registry as administrator.
here a sequence of pictures:




Now what really did the trick was from the same place I had create the share I run:
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'NET USE * /DELETE /YES'

This got rid of the share.
